# bash variable substitution right next to another string

Tags: bash

How do you replace a bash variable right next to a string so the variable you are replacing is not misinterpreted?

For Instance::

```
NUMBER=33
echo "$NUMBERs"
```

In my case I want this to echo out "33s" but bash is interpereting this variable as "$NUMBERs" when I want it to be "$NUMBER"

Comment: `echo "${NUMBER}s"`

Comment: That was it, thanks!

Comment: @anubhava Why answer in a comment? Post in a proper answer so you can get credit and more importantly future searchers will know that the question has an answer that worked.

Comment: @Gary_W: I was under impression that it must be a duplicate but so far I haven't found exact dup

Comment: More dupes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26559617/bash-variable-interpolation-separate-variables-by-a-hyphen-or-underscore, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46305806/bash-while-read-loop-does-not-properly-recognize-variables, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43416413/inserting-variable-into-sh-script-command, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42196891/bash-variable-not-getting-expanded-properly

Comment: @anubhava Fair enough then :-)